# Notification using Alarm manager not working properly for kitkat and lollipop versions

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-4.4-kitkat

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(CubeActivity.this, MyReciever.class);

        SharedPreferences shared = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("notification5", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();    
        editor.putInt("minutes", (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) )-1);
        editor.commit();

        myIntent.putExtra("minutes", (shared.getInt("minutes", 0)));

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(CubeActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,shared.getInt("minutes", 0), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Please explain your question properly.

Comment: Using alarm manager .set() method , some notifications are coming after 24 hours and then irregularly after that in kikat and lollipop phones.

Comment: Beginning in API 19, the trigger time passed to this method is treated as inexact. Read this -http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: Why using `shared.getInt("minutes", 0)` when setting **Alarm Manager**.

Answer (score 0):

You use `shared.getInt("minutes", 0)` as the trigger time. However, the trigger time should be time in milliseconds that the alarm should go off.

According to the api docs:

> public void set (int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation)
>
> type   int: One of ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC, or RTC_WAKEUP.
>
> triggerAtMillis    long: time in milliseconds that the alarm should go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).
>
> operation  PendingIntent: Action to perform when the alarm goes off; typically comes from IntentSender.getBroadcast().

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,shared.getInt("minutes", 0), pendingIntent);
```

Use below code:

```
long TICK_TIME = 60*1000;  //the time to trigger alarm manager rite now its 1 minute  
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), TICK_TIME, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: I want the alarm to trigger every 24 hours. What parameters should I use?

Comment: 24*60*60*1000 for 24 hours.